# requireJS - file names and folder conventions and dependency resolution

Tags: requirejs

I am using steve sanderson's yeoman knockout scaffolding described [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/).

However I have one issue which is if I decide to create folders for different types of modules, and If I then want to inject one of these modules into my components using folder name conventions then I have to use a very verbose path resolution like `"../../services/service"`.

```js
define(["knockout", "text!./home.html","../../services/service"], function(ko, homeTemplate, service) {

  function HomeViewModel(route) {
    this.message = ko.observable('Welcome to App!');
  }

  HomeViewModel.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    this.message('You invoked doSomething() on the viewmodel.');
  };

  return { viewModel: HomeViewModel, template: homeTemplate };

});
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. For example just being able to use folder name and file name like `"services/service"`

Answer (score 1):

The `paths` configuration is your answer ([ref](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths)). In your configuration do:

```js
require.config({
    // ...
    paths: {
        'services': 'path/to/services/folder'
    },
    // ...
})
```

Now you can require the `path/to/services/folder/myservice.js` module from *any* other module as:

```js
define(['services/myservice'], function(myservice) {
    // ...
});
```